# Responsive layout, need support

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, grid

I'm stuck with some css and need your help.
I need to achieve the effect shown on the image. The problem for now - is the responsiveness of the layout, I want those tiles to change their size when the size of the browser changes and display them one under another on a mobile. I tried flexbox here but have some issues with the effect I want to achieve.

[image]

Here is my html:

```
        <section class="tiles">
        <div class="first-tile">
            <div class="tile-img">
                <img src="./assets/tile-img.webp" alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="tile-content">
                <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="side-tiles">
            <div class="second-tile">
                <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="third-tile">
                <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: try  .tiles{flex-warp:wrap}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `display:grid`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.bloc {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bloc:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 95px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="bloc">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620654458802-d9392aa95664?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyMzI1MzM0NA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      <h4> Lorem</h4>
      <p>Lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bloc"></div>
  <div class="bloc"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it might work. What about the image inside the first tile? How to change its size depending on the tile size?

Comment: You juste add a selector to the `img` and set its `width`

Comment: I edited the snippet so you can have a good basis for your project